# VBA Advanced AutoFilter + Create new sheets based on range

Tags: vba, excel, tabs, advanced-filter

I need to create new tabs in a workbook based upon a range of cells in a worksheet template. I also want to delete rows of data that do not match the tab name. For example, from the table below I would have a new tab named "2206 - 6" and only data associated with that would remain, keeping in mind that this range of data will change each time the macro is used.

**Before**:

[image]

**After**:

[image]

---

Interval Number
2206 - 6
6304 - 5
4102 - 20

The table begins in row 11, but I need to retain all of the information above. I have an Advanced Filter Macro that gets close to what I want, but its doing two things I don't want: creating empty tabs and not retaining information above row 11.

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    vcol = 1
    Set ws = Sheets("Offshore Searches")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A11:G20"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And _
          Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

I also have a macro which creates tabs based on a range without the advanced filter, so each tab looks identical (just the tab name changes)

```
Sub CreateWorkSheetByRange()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    arr = WorkRng.Value
    Sheets("Offshore Searches").Select
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Application.ActiveSheet)
            ws.Name = arr(i, j)
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Range("A1").Select
        Next
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Is there a way to both create tabs based on a range while simultaneously using an advanced filter?

Comment: Can you show a resulting tab as well? (one expected result)

Comment: I just updated the post with the "Resulting tab" picture and here is the link as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY4uZ.png

Comment: ok, I'll update your question to include both images - we prefer all images included in the question because some users don't have access to other sites

Comment: That makes total sense - thank you so much Paul! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option (tested)

All functions bellow, in a separate module
It copies the main sheet, deletes the button and uses auto filter to remove unneeded rows

---

> This uses dictionaries and **late binding is slow**: <strike>CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")</strike>
>
> **Early binding is fast**: VBA Editor -> **Tools** -> **References** -> Add **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Const X As String = vbNullString
Public Sub CreateTabs()
    Const FIRST_CELL    As String = "Interval Number"
    Const LAST_CELL     As String = "Vesting Doc Number (LC/RS)"
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet, d As Dictionary, i As Long
    Dim fr As Long, lr As Long, fc As Long, found As Range, rng As Range, val As String

    SetDisplay False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Offshore Searches")
    Set found = FindCell(ws.UsedRange, FIRST_CELL)
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        fr = found.Row + 1
        fc = found.Column
    End If
    Set found = FindCell(ws.UsedRange, LAST_CELL)
    If Not found Is Nothing Then lr = found.Row - 1

    If fr > 0 And fc > 0 And lr >= fr Then
        If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
        Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fr, fc), ws.Cells(lr, fc))
        Dim arr As Variant, r As Long
        arr = rng
        Set d = New Dictionary
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
            val = Trim(CStr(arr(r, 1)))
            val = CleanWsName(val)
            If Not d.Exists(val) Then d.Add r, val
        Next
        For i = 1 To d.Count
          If Not WsExists(d(i)) Then
            ws.Copy After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
            Set wsNew = wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
            With wsNew
             .Name = d(i): If .Shapes.Count = 1 Then wsNew.Shapes.Item(1).Delete
             Set rng = .Range(.Cells(fr - 1, fc), .Cells(lr, fc))
         rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & d(i), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"
             Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
             rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
             rng.AutoFilter
            End With
          End If
        Next
    End If
    ws.Activate
    SetDisplay True
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub SetDisplay(Optional ByVal status As Boolean = False)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = status
    Application.DisplayAlerts = status
End Sub

Public Function FindCell(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal celVal As String) As Range
    Dim found As Range
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If Len(celVal) > 0 Then
            Set found = rng.Find(celVal, MatchCase:=True)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then Set FindCell = found
        End If
    End If
End Function

Public Function CleanWsName(ByVal wsName As String) As String
    Const x = vbNullString
    wsName = Trim$(wsName)    'Trim, then remove [ ] / \ < > : * ? | "
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "[", x), "]", x), " ", x)
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "/", x), "\", x), ":", x)
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "<", x), ">", x), "*", x)
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "?", x), "|", x), Chr(34), x)
    If Len(wsName) = 0 Then wsName = "DT " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss")
    CleanWsName = Left$(wsName, 31)         'Resize to max len of 31
End Function

Public Function WsExists(ByVal wsName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If ws.Name = wsName Then
                WsExists = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

---

Assumptions

- Interval Numbers format is consistent: Unit & " - " & Week (=B12 & " - " & C12)
- Interval Numbers are not longer than 31 character, and don't contain these special chars: [ ] / \ ? * .

  - If so, the sheet names will be shortened to 31 chars
  - and all special chars mentioned removed (Excel limitation for Sheet names)
- Working row starts after cell "Interval Number" and stop before "Vesting Doc Number (LC/RS)"
- There are no spaces before or after "Interval Number" and "Vesting Doc Number (LC/RS)"
- Main tab name is exactly "Offshore Searches", and it contains only one button ("Create Tabs")

Comment: Same to you Paul! This is awesome! I still only know enough about VBA to be dangerous and there is no way I could have done this on my own. Thank you, thank you, so much. It works perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! please click on the check mark on the top-left of the answer to mark it as accepted, if it works

Answer (score 1):

For what you have shown in the images, you may try something like this to achieve that...

```
Sub InsertSheets()
Dim sws As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim slr As Long, i As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set sws = Sheets("Sheet1")
If sws.Range("A12").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Interval Numbers found on the sheet.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
slr = sws.Range("A11").End(xlDown).Row
Set Rng = sws.Range("A12:A" & slr)
For Each Cell In Rng
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(Cell.Value).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    sws.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Name = Cell.Value
    ws.DrawingObjects.Delete
    With ws
        For i = slr To 12 Step -1
            If i <> Cell.Row Then ws.Rows(i).Delete
        Next i
    End With
    Set ws = Nothing
Next Cell
sws.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I could kiss you right now! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Aimaria Glad it worked as per your requirement. And thanks for your sweet kiss. :)